# How to normalize a bigger-than-memory dask array?

Tags: dask

I'm trying to normalize a dask array with a reduction of itself (e.g., `b = a / a.sum()` with `a` and `b` being dask arrays).  Computation of this normalized array will first compute everything necessary to know the original array and only then calculate the divisions and hence spill to disk if memory is not sufficient.

Code example:

```py
from dask.distributed import Client
from dask import arry as da

# Create 1000 MB array full of 1's of with chunks of 50MB
a = da.ones(shape=(1/8 * 1000e6, 1), chunks=(1/8 * 50e6, 1))

# Create normalized array with sum = 1
b = a / a.sum()

# Create cluster to small for all of a or b at once
client = Client(n_workers=1, threads_per_worker=1, memory_limit=500e6)

# Compute sum of b  (Spills to disk)
print(b.sum().compute())
```

Is there something like the following?

```
b = a / same_as_a_but_different_tasks.sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by copying the array and renaming all tasks in the top layer:

```py
from copy import deepcopy


def copy_with_renamed_top_layer(a, prepend_name="copy-of-"):
    # copy array and dask
    b = a.copy()
    b.dask = deepcopy(b.dask)

    # get new name
    orig_name = a.name
    new_name = prepend_name + orig_name

    # rename dependencies
    b.dask.dependencies[new_name] = b.dask.dependencies.pop(orig_name)

    # rename tasks of uppermost layer
    b.dask.layers[new_name] = b.dask.layers.pop(orig_name)
    b.dask.layers[new_name] = {
        (new_name, ) + k[1:]: v
        for k, v in b.dask.layers[new_name].items()
    }

    # rename array
    b.name = new_name

    return b


# Create 1000 MB array full of 1's of with chunks of 50MB
a = da.ones(shape=(1/8 * 1000e6, 1), chunks=(1/8 * 50e6, 1))

# copy and rename uppermost layer
a_copy = copy_with_renamed_top_layer(a)

# Create normalized array with sum = 1
b = a / a_copy.sum()
```

This is, however, a highly fragile solution as it relies on the current internal API.